# What is the meaning of regexp_split in dremio?

Tags: sql, dremio

I have following code which I wrote in dremio.

Could you please tell me what is the meaning of this syntax? I tried to find, but I couldn't. I followed the tutorial in dremio, but I need to know what are the other sql functions we can use in dremio, 
specially for string and regular expressions? Also what are the other functions we can use in dremio as sql or else?

Here shop_names are in a list

01_bike,02_car,03_car,125_01,112_03,113_moto,112_678

```
select id, regexp_split(shop_names, '\Q,\E', 'ALL', 10) as new_shopes_names 
from table1
```

Comment: I can only guess it means spit on comma (,) but the \Q and \E isn't something I recognize from other regular expression implementations.

Comment: A Google search for `Dremio help functions` takes you to their documentation to answer the questions you have posed.